# ActiveAdmin: Issue with permitted params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activeadmin

When trying to update a user in ActiveAdmin, I get the following error:

```
Unpermitted parameter: :roles. Context: { controller: Admin::UsersController, action: update, request: #<ActionDispatch::Request:0x0000000110f2ff88>, params: {"_method"=>"patch", "authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "user"=>{"email"=>"user@localhost.com", "name"=>"User", "organization_id"=>"12", "partner_id"=>"1", "invite_now"=>"1", "social_listening_access"=>"0"}, "roles"=>{"global"=>[""], "partner"=>[""]}, "commit"=>"Update User", "controller"=>"admin/users", "action"=>"update", "id"=>"27"} }`
```

Here's how I set the permitted params:

```
permit_params :email, :name, :organization_id, :partner_id, :social_listening_access, :invite_now, roles_attributes: [:global, :partner]
```

Basically, I believe I need to permit params for both the user and roles. I can't move the roles attributes inside user.

I tried different ways of setting my permit_params. I am open to suggestions.

Comment: It doesn’t look like that controller is receiving anything called “roles_attributes”… what happens if you use params.permit(… roles:[…]) instead?

Comment: @iftheshoefritz I am getting a different kind of error, but I am probably misusing the params.permit(… roles:[…]). I placed it on top of my update method since that's where it was erring out first. Now it complains about other missing params, so it's probably overriding what was there before.